# How to use Jquery Mobile data-url

Tags: jquery-mobile

I just want to know how to use the **data-url** attribute, i have a seperate page `page2.html` which i want to navigate to on the link click

```
<a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
```

in the same page, i placed another page

```
<div id="page2" data-role="page"  data-url="page2.html">
</div>
```

**page2.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h3>header</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when i click on the link, it shows the page url in url bar, but returns a blank page, what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your link to

```
<a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
```

Get rid of your page2 div in the main page.

In page2.html, you can set the id of the page div.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="page2"  data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h3>header</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

jQM will automatically load the first data-role="page" div it finds in page2.html via AJAX into the DOM of the main page. You don't need data-url for navigating pages.

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, i know  how to navigate to other pages and pages in the same page, in single page application i will have all the div data-role="page" in  the same page and contents of that pages in seperate html pages, so i just want to load the contents to the div with data-url when user click on the links, if u can provide me an example of usage of data-url